# Retrieving DisplayField values from ExtJs form

Tags: extjs

**Hi**,

I have developed a extjs form using Jsp which contains DisplayFields. Now I want to retrieve DisplayField values into controller or Servlet.

Any hint with the code will help.

Answer (score 0):

Some code to look at would help, but assuming you have a display field with an id of 'myDisplayField' you can, in it's simplest form, use:

```
var theValue = Ext.getCmp('myDisplayField').getValue();
```